# Asterisk Move the bridged call in to meete conference

Tags: asterisk

A call to B and both bridge and can talk , I would like to launch a AMI script 
which can put both the callers on a same meetme conference room 
is this possible ???, if yes pls tell me how can we achieve this

Answer (score 1):

You can use ami "transfer" command to transfer both legs to dialplan. After that you can use dialplan to go conference.

Check this page for examples:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+n-way+call+HOWTO